# Use a different folder for assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For a Rails application I am making I want to be able to switch 'themes' using a configuration file. The theme does not need to switch dynamically (while running, but will be known when the application starts).

I moved my `stylesheets` directory out of my `assets` directory, to a folder called : `/app/themes/[themename]/assets/stylesheets`.

The idea is to have multiple folders in the `/app/themes` directory, which can be used by the application.

*REMARK:* I didn't move my `javascripts` folder from the assets folder, because I still want to use that globally.

In my layout I use the following code, to load controller specific stylesheets:

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "#{controller_name}" if MyApp::Application.assets.find_asset("#{controller_name}") %>`

Of course, my application no longer knows where my assets are and it serves me a page, where the assets are not loading (because of the `if` check mentioned above).

I added the following code to my `config/initializers/assets.rb` to make sure it also loads the assets from the *theme* directory:

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/themes/#{Settings.site.theme}/assets/**/").each do |path|
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << path
end
```

`Settings.site.theme` is a string value which is filled correctly and now the stylesheets actually load on the website. So **YAY**!

But here is the thing, the minute I change the `config.assets.compile` to `false`, it all fails (so on test and production).

`MyApp::Application.assets.find_asset("#{controller_name}")` is throwing the exception `undefined method`find_asset' for nil:NilClass`.

I am on Rails 5.0.0.1.

Anyone got an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simpler way would be to namespace the themes *under* the stylesheets. That is, have a folder structure like this:

```
- app
  - assets
    - stylesheets
      - theme-blue
        - application.scss
      - theme-red
        - application.scss
    - javascripts
      - application.js
```

And then, in your layout file, you just point the `stylesheet_link_tag` to `theme-blue/application`, like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "theme-blue/application" %>
```

Another way to do this is have multiple layouts, one for `theme-blue` and another one for `theme-red`. In the controller, do

```
class BlueController < ApplicationController
  layout "theme_blue"
end
```

And the file `app/views/layouts/theme_blue.html.erb` will require the right css file.

You might need to add the scss files to `config/assets.rb`, but Rails will tell you if you need that.